# corrcoef function of matlab works wrongly

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix, correlation, error-correction

I used corrcoef function of matlab to find correlation between two images. 
First I use Correlation between all corresponding points

```
A_2=double(imread('prometmonew1.tif'));
B_2=double(imread('lai5min1bas1.tif'));
R = corrcoef(A_2(:),B_2(:))
```

The result is

```
R =

    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000
```

but when I remove some parts of the images (backgrounds) and then I use this function again the correlation is different(the values of backgrounds are negative), how is it possible? whats wrong?

```
V=find(A_2>=0);
A=A_2(V);
V_1=find(B_2>=0);
B=B_2(V_1);

R = corrcoef(A,B)

R =

    1.0000    0.3275
    0.3275    1.0000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am equally puzzled. However, check the size of A and B relative to A_2 and B_2. Is it possible that you had so much data at zero (background) and resulting correlation rounded to 1.0000 (i.e., 0.99998766). Then after filter the correlation calculation is not dominated by zeros?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The total number of pixels is 28210 and the Number of background pixels is 14633. It means for all of pixels correlation is 1 for 14633 correlation is 0.3275,  how this can be possible ?

Comment: Next recommendation is to track a few elements before and after you drop background elements for "A" and "B". That is if A_2(1000:1100) were non-background and become A(100:200) after dropping background. Then see what happens in B ... hopefully same thing. If that doesn't work then just pull out and do same analysis with just the first 200 elements and see what happens ... that should make the analysis small enough to look at the numerical data side-by-side.